grep REGEX parse html for email
I've got just over 1000 html pages to grep and extract email addresses.  My issue is the command I'm using below is returning javascript strings like @typeface where @ is present in with the email addresses I'm trying to get. wondering if there are any recommendations for ignoring these unwanted strings and only getting the email addresses
grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' temp9.txt | sort | uniq -i 


Are you able to use any html parsing libraries? Don't use regex with HTML

A quick solution to the very issue you're reporting would be to simply change *s to +s in your regex. A more robust solution should involve an actual HTML parser and a better rounded regex that validates an email address.

Obligatory link about the futility of trying to parse X/HTML with regex can be found here.. Stop what you're doing, and use a DOM parser instead.

This was closed as a dup of how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression but I reopened it as that's a question about how to check if a string you already have is a valid email address while this is a question about how to find strings that look like email addresses in a block of text - those are 2 quite different problems.

The immediate issue is that *  means literally "zero or more". If you want one or more, that's +.

FWIW I'd use a regexp like
grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]._%+-]{2,}@[[:alnum:].-]{2,}\.[[:alpha:]]{2,}'

to get a good-enough-for-me list of email addresses from a file. If you need something perfect then you should find some other solution.
You should not escape regexp metachars inside bracket expressions as a) that's not necessary, b) it's undefined behavior, and c) it can turn the char into a metachar in some greps. So [[:alnum:]+\.\_\-] should be [[:alnum:]+._-].
You also want at least 1 of those chars each side of the @ (personally, I test for 2 as I find some garbage sometimes if I test for just 1) so you need to use + or {2,} instead of * as the repetition metachar (and add -E to the grep args).
Also make sure to add a regexp segment to match at least a couple of letters after a . at the end so you ensure the string ends in .com or .uk or similar TLD.
See also https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html but most regexps described there are PCREs so you could only use them in grep if it's GNU grep and you use grep -P instead of grep -E.

The domain regex could be tightened up some more; initial or final dashes are disallowed, adjacent dots are disallowed, duplicated dashes are only permitted in a very limited context (basically after @xn). If the HTML is well-formed you'd really only want to extract well-formed href elements with a mailto: protocol but then that's what Ken White already pointed out in a multiply-upvoted comment.

@triplee sure, as I mentioned the regexp I showed is good-enough-for-me. I added "If you need something perfect then you should find some other solution." to make that clearer.
